# Is it bad to put a certificate as CA in Firefox?

Tags: tls

I know I can add a self-signed certificate from a website to Firefox, but only in the CA list of it.

**Question:** does this mean I have to ultimately trust that self-signed certificate? Can someone sign with that self-signed certificate ex.: google.com, and since the cert is in my CA list, I wouldn't notice when visiting google.com via HTTPS that there is a MITM ongoing?

Comment: PKI is about trust so you have to trust the signer of the self-signed cert and control that private key used to sign same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to trust on that self-signed certificate Certificate because you have added it in your browser. But to create a new certificate signed by this CA you must have **private key** of the CA. So no body else can create certificate signed by your CA.